# Differentiation operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T be the operator of differentiation in the space P45(R) of polynomials
of degree at most 45. Find the matrix of T^23 in the standard basis which
is {1, x, . . . , x^45}.

I understand the matrix T will look like
(0 1 0 … 0),(0 0 2 … 0),…(0 0 0 … 45),(0 0 0 … 0)

But how could I power it by 23 and get T^23

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Can you not figure out the 23rd derivative of $x^n$, $n=0,1,\dotsc,45$?

Comment: Isn’t it going to be a huge number that’s hard to list out?

Comment: Don't guess. Write the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and so on derivative and look for a pattern. You will be surprised how simple it is.

Comment: You don't have to write out a huge number, if you can write out a compact formula for that number instead. E.g., for many purposes, $2^{20}$ is just as good as an answer to a question as $1048576$ is.